# Custom permalink accept any params

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I need to create a custom permalink structure, I want to show m custom taxonomy in the url, something like:

```
www.example.com/ristoranti/italia/milano/my-post-slug
```

The first segment is the post category, added with WP Categories menu.
`italia` and `milano` are taxonomies created with a custom plugin where `milano` is child of `italia`:

```
function mlt_create_custom_taxonomies()
{
    $labels = [
        'name'              => _x( 'Locations', 'taxonomy general name', 'mlt' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Location', 'taxonomy singular name', 'mlt' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Locations', 'mlt' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Locations', 'mlt' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Location', 'mlt' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:', 'mlt' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Location', 'mlt' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Location', 'mlt' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Location', 'mlt' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Location Name', 'mlt' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Location', 'mlt' ),
    ];

    $args = [
        'labels' => $labels,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical'        => true, ),
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_tagcloud'       => false,
    ];

    register_taxonomy( 'location', [ 'post' ], $args );
}
add_action('init', 'mlt_create_custom_taxonomies');
```

To add the custom taxonomies to the url I have edited my permalink structure like that:

```
/%category%/%location%/%postname%/
```

I have also added a rewrite rule for `%location%` in order to add the taxonomies:

```
function location_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {

    if ('post' == $post->post_type) {
        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'location' ) ) {                
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $tax_array[] = $term->slug;
            }
            $link = str_replace( '%location%', implode('/',$tax_array), $link );
        }
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'location_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

With this code I'm able to create the link.

The problem is that if I create a fake url like:

`www.example.com/ristoranti/XXXXX/XXXX/my-post-slug` I'm able to see the post, while the `XXXX/XXX` are completely wrong.

How is this possibile? How can I make sure that the taxonomy are correct in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, I suppose, just how the query parser works. If you create a new `WP_Query` instance, and provide a post `name`, any taxonomy parameters you add will be ignored and will not be added to the query. Post uniqueness is determined entirely based on post slug, and uniqueness of slug is enforced.

It's possible to fix, but I don't really think it's necessary. How would these random incorrect URLs be generated? If you visit one of these false URLs, you'll see that the canonical link is the correct one, so search engines would not index these bad URLs, if they were somehow encountered.

So, that said, here's a fix. Hook a function to `wp`, which is after the query is run, but before the template is loaded. Here we can check if it's a singular post, get the ID of queried post, and check if it actually has these terms. If it doesn't, we generate a 404.

```
function wpd_check_singular_post_terms() {
    global $wp_query;
    if( is_singular( 'post' )
    && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['location'] )
    && isset( $wp_query->query_vars['category_name'] ) ) {
        if( ! has_term( $wp_query->query_vars['location'], 'location', get_queried_object_id() )
        || ! has_term( $wp_query->query_vars['category_name'], 'category', get_queried_object_id() ) ){
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header( 404 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpd_check_singular_post_terms' );
```

Note that the result is now not actually a 404! Surprise! Setting a 404 makes the `redirect_guess_404_permalink` function kick in, which gets the correct permalink for the requested post name, and 301 redirects there.

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify a little the second if but your code gave me a starting point!